# Where is the react-devtool?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, reactjs

[image]

As you see ,I installed it on my Chrome.
But there isn't react tool on my development tools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, It's not possible to have React Dev Tools in Chrome. Please have a look at this official link:

http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/known-issues.html#content

> It's currently not possible to use the "React" tab in the devtools to inspect app widgets. This is due to a change in how the application scripts are evaluated in the devtools plugin; they are now run inside a Web Worker, and the plugin is unaware of this and so unable to communicate properly with React Native.
>
> However, you can still use the Console feature of the devtools, and debugging JavaScript with breakpoints works too. To use the console, make sure to select the ⚙debuggerWorker.js entry in the devtools dropdown that by default is set to .

There is also an open issue on github. Please have a look at this as well:

https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/issues/229

> React Native now runs within a Web Worker on Chrome so that it gets a more pure and isolated JS environment that more closely mimics JSC on the device but this breaks the React devtools. @skevy pointed this out and I didn't see a task open yet. The fix might need to happen on the RN side but I figured that people thinking about the devtools are more likely to have a solution come to mind.
>
> **Repro**: Run an app with RN master, run it in the Chrome debugger, try to use React devtools but "React" option doesn't show in the Web Inspector.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

It's enabled only if your webpage is using react, I'm using it now.